# Subclassing a View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a single view aplicaition on xcode with several view controllers and xib files in it. I am trying to subclass a xib file's view controller called ViewControllerPg62 as a sub class of a view controller called ViewController. How can i do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

Why are you working with XIB files? You should be using Storyboards.

I had to go back to an old project using XIBs to see how they worked.

In an XIB you should see an entry called "Placeholders", and under that, an item called "File's Owner." That represents the object that owns and manages the views in the XIB. Select that, and then display the Identity Inspector. There will be an entry at the top "Custom Class" where you can change the class that manages this view controller.

Before changing that, I suggest you create the source file for your view controller ("ViewController.swift", in your case.) Then when you change the class of the owning object, the XIB will create an instance of your custom class when that XIB is invoked.

The approach is quite similar for Storyboards, although it's a little more coherent.

Comment: Ok, what's what's with the down-vote? If you think my answer is somehow lacking, please leave a comment explaining why.